# Alt + arrow sometimes rotates screen, sometimes functioning as "back" in browser

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, lenovo-laptop

I have a LENOVO ideapad 510 with Windows 10 installed. The combinations <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> are supposed to control the browser's (Chrome) back/forward functions. But, sometimes the combination rotates the screen instead of doing one of these functions.

**How can I configure these combinations to always do the back/forward functions in the browser?**

Comment: Are you sure you are pressing `Alt + Arrow key`, not `Ctrl + Alt + Arrow key`? `Ctrl + Alt + Arrow key` is shortcut for rotating screen (its not a shortcut of Chrome, but Intel graphics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys may be both labeled <kbd>Alt</kbd> but the right one is in fact <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. In Windows you can emulate <kbd>AltGr</kbd> by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>. You can read more [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key).

As PrashantKumar96 reported in his comment, shortcuts for rotating the screen use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier while Chrome uses <kbd>Alt</kbd> only.

Solution: always use left <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: Is there a reason then why the right Alt switches functions seemingly randomly?

Comment: @Joshhh I would not expect it to do so. I thought you just didn't realize both Alt keys are different. Do you use (i.e. switch between) multiple keyboard layouts maybe?

Comment: Nope. Sometimes when I press Right Alt + Arrow it goes back/forward, sometimes it rotates the screen (even when there is a page to go back to i.e. the back button is not disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Reason for rotation of screen is that right Alt is actually AltGr(Alt-Graph), which has many other function for non US keyboard or US-International keyboard.

Solution- change your keyboard to US keyboard.(US International keyboard is different from US keyboard so keep it US keyboard.)

If you are using US keyboard then their is no difference between right and left alt. By pressing Alt+left arrow you can go back easily.

Hope this help.